# Can't create a new web site in SP Designer with Local Admin permission

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to set up a SharePoint system in my work place.
The administrator installed SharePoint server 2010 on a Windows server 2008 R2 virtual machine with his "domain-admin" permission and gave my username a "local-admin" permission.
I then installed sharePoint Designer 2010 on that virtual machine but when I try to create a New Blank Web Site I get a "Windows Security" popup which asks for my user/pass.
After I give them it asks for them again repeatedly. If I cancel the popup I get a message:

"This web site must be created on a server that is running Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Please choose another location."

But when I try to create the site with the administrator's user (which has domain-admin" permission I succeed.

I also installed SP Designer on my local machine but I only get the same message "This web site must...".

How can I make it work with my user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint couldn't care less if you're local admin or domain admin. What it cares about is which rights your user has been granted in SharePoint Central Administration.

You should be setup as one of the Site collection admins of the Site collection you're going to set up.

I would recommend that you start by creating a playground in which you can play around knowing that you'll delete it when you get more experience with SharePoint.

And you should probably start by sites/lists/pages etc. in the browser before you go to SharePoint Designer

Comment: Right. It was just about selecting a site-collection/web-application. I think that when creating a new site in the designer if the message had been "Choose the site-collection/web-application" instead of "specify the location of the new web site" that could prevent some confusion. Anyway, thanks, problem solved.